# How to upsert into elasticsearch in spark?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, pyspark

With HTTP POST, the following script can insert a new field `createtime` or update `lastupdatetime`:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
"doc": {
    "lastupdatetime": "2015-09-16T18:00:00"
}
"upsert" : {
    "createtime": "2015-09-16T18:00:00"
    "lastupdatetime": "2015-09-16T18:00",
}
}'
```

But in spark script, after setting `"es.write.operation": "upsert"`, i don't know how to insert `createtime` at all. There is only `es.update.script.*` in the [official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-update)... So, can anyone give me an example?

**UPDATE**: In my case, i want to save the information of android devices from log into **one** elasticsearch type, and set it's first appearance time as `createtime`. If the device appear again, i only update the `lastupdatetime`, but leave the `createtime` as it was.

So the document `id` is android ID, if the id exists, update `lastupdatetime`, else insert `createtime` and `lastupdatetime`.So the setting here is(in python):

```
conf = {
    "es.resource.write": "stats-device/activation",
    "es.nodes": "NODE1:9200",
    "es.write.operation": "upsert",
    "es.mapping.id": "id"
    # ???
}

rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=conf
)
```

I just don't know how to insert a **new** field if the `id` not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i got a solution which is not perfect:

1. add `createtime` to all source doc;
2. save to es with `create` method and ignore already created error;
3. remove `createtime` field;
4. save to es again with `update` method;

For now(2015-09-27), step 2 can be implemented by [this patch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/308).

Comment: If I may ask, what's the 409?

Comment: Can you post the whole error you are getting? It seems like you are confusing 409 with some other thing. Because Elasticsearch updates by default an already existing document!

Comment: Note that first i use `create`, not `update`. If `id` already exist in Elasticsearch, an exception will be thrown but the doc will not be changed. Here the exception is **already created**.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your Spark script, it will be hard to give a detailed answer. But in general you will want to use [elasticsearch-hadoop](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) (so you'll need to add that dependency to your Build.sbt file, e.g.) and then in your script you can:

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark._ 
val documents = sc.parallelize(Seq(Map(
                                   "id" -> 1, 
                                   "createtime" -> "2015-09-16T18:00:00"
                                   "lastupdatetime" -> "2015-09-16T18:00"),
                                  Map(<next document>), ...)
                   .saveToEs("test/type1", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))
```

as per the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html). The second argument to saveToES specifies which key in your RDD of Maps to use as the ElasticSearch document id.

Of course, if you're doing this with Spark it implies you've got more rows than you'll want to type out by hand, so for your case you'd need to transform your data into an RDD of Maps from key -> value within your script. But without knowing the data sources I can't go into much more detail.

Comment: Then setting setting es.write.operation to upsert as  you have done and then using rdd.saveToEs() should do what you want.

Comment: No, `createtime` should never be updated. Directly using `upsert` will overwrite this field.

Comment: I see. So you want to do a partial-document upsert. E.g. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update.html#upserts